# Custom Phabricator login or registration page

Tags: phabricator

How can I display some guidelines on the registration page, or if this is not possible some guidelines on the login page?

[image: Registration page]

Answer (score 1):

from at least version:

`a20f108034126ff7dc45604dec80319e1ec76172 (Sat, Feb 9)`

it is possible to add message for the on-boarding.  You can find the configuration in:
https://your-phabricator-instance/auth/message/